# Windows: Minimize a non-responding window

Tags: windows

I have a window that is doing some long calculation. I want to minimize it, so I could access my desktop, but it doesn't respond to events (one thread busy calculating). I would have expected this to be fixed in win8.1?

In linux: Click minimize, the window is minimized no matter what.

I assume the the difference is that on linux the os is responsible for the window toolbar events, and permissions what it can do.

Comment: Do you want to minimize it "programmatically" or just as a Windows user?

Comment: I posted in superuser and not stackexchange, so I guess I asked as a user.

Answer (score 0):

No, the difference is the window ghosting feature, take a look: [DisableProcessWindowsGhosting()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648415%28VS.85%29.aspx).

> Disables the window ghosting feature for the calling GUI process.
>   Window ghosting is a Windows Manager feature that lets the user
>   minimize, move, or close the main window of an application that is not
>   responding.

To disable it  you can use the Application Compatibility Toolkit to create and install a custom Application Compatibility database to disable the Ghost Window feature for your program.

To download the Application Compatibility Toolkit, visit the [following Microsoft Web site.](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286552.aspx)

Comment: So is there a registry flag that I can set as a user, so the window ghosting would always be available and no app could bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows the application handles the UI repaints. If the programmer used the UI thread to also do calculations, then you're stuck. It's not the Window version's fault, it's less-than-elegant programming by the app's author. ;)

Microsoft has very good documentation covering the phenomenon you are describing, and how application programmers can avoid it.

[Preventing Hangs in Windows Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765(v=vs.85).aspx)

Intro blurb:

> Users like responsive applications. When they click a menu, they want the application to react instantly, even if it is currently printing their work. When they save a lengthy document in their favorite word processor, they want to continue typing while the disk is still spinning. Users get impatient rather quickly when the application does not react in a timely fashion to their input.
>
> A programmer might recognize many legitimate reasons for an application not to instantly respond to user input. The application might be busy recalculating some data, or simply waiting for its disk I/O to complete. However, from user research, we know that users get annoyed and frustrated after just a couple of seconds of unresponsiveness. After 5 seconds, they will try to terminate a hung application. Next to crashes, application hangs are the most common source of user disruption when working with Win32 applications.

Best Practices blurb:

> **Keep the UI Thread Simple**
>
> The UI thread's primary responsibility is to retrieve and dispatch
> messages. Any other kind of work introduces the risk of hanging the
> windows owned by this thread.
>
> **Do:**
>
> - Move resource-intensive or unbounded algorithms that result in long-running operations to worker threads
> - Identify as many blocking function calls as possible and try to move them to worker threads; any function calling into another DLL should
>   be suspicious
> - Make an extra effort to remove all file I/O and networking API calls from your worker thread. These functions can block for many seconds if
>   not minutes. If you need to do any kind of I/O in the UI thread,
>   consider using asynchronous I/O
> - Be aware that your UI thread is also servicing all single-threaded apartment (STA) COM servers hosted by your process; if you make a
>   blocking call, these COM servers will be unresponsive until you
>   service the message queue again

Comment: Gee, I feel so fortunate that they didn't trust the programmer not to trample other processes memory or perform other operations that might cause system instabilities, at least not without the proper security :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with even one app that when it gets stuck due to a bug or a calculation you can minimize it.